# Mount Path for static assets in Meteor

Tags: meteor

When running a `Meteor` application the assets in `<script>` tags are relative to the root path, like `<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/routes.js?baa7082cd1947c1ebf3cdabc08bfe8701bd770af"></script>`

I'm trying to point an `nginx` server to it from a different path, e.g.`example.com/my-app` but since the assets are still pointing relative to the root path  they don't get loaded. 
E.g. `example.com/app/routes.js` instead of `example.com/my-app/routes.js`

In `webpack` I could just specify a `publicPath` and the assets will point relative to it. Is there something similar that I can do in `Meteor`?

Answer (score 0):

The files should be in `public` directory in the root.
For example if the structure is `public/images` the `src` of image will be `/images/imagefile.jpg`. Same for `javascript`.

The files can be referred as `/assets/public/images`